# Android Studio blue screens when trying to make a signed APK

Tags: android, bsod

I attempted several times to create a signed APK for an app I'm making on Android Studio 0.9.2. I used the signed APK option in the menu and also attempted it using the in-built console. It seems to blue screen whenever it trying to bring to date a debug file. If anyone has any idea on how to prevent blue screen at least I'd be grateful :).

Comment: Minidumps -if any- would be a great help in order to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got so fed up with Android Studio giving me BSOD that I uninstalled AS and installed Eclipse.  As soon as I started Eclipse it gave me a BSOD.  After checking on the Eclipse forum I checked and found that I had two releases of Java (7 and 8) on my system.  I uninstalled both versions of Java and I uninstalled Java SDK then I reinstalled Java 8 and Java SDK 8 and everything is working just fine.

I have decided not to go back to Android Studio to see if that is fixed too.